# Loop: Copy paragraph based on excel list from one document to another using bookmark

Tags: excel, vba, loops, ms-word, paragraph

Please refer below screenshot for more details.

Excel Sheet

[image: Excel sheet]

Source Document

[image: Source Document]

Below my code output in Destination Document
[image: Below my code output in Destination Document]

Macropod output in Destination Document

[image: Macropod output in Destination Document]

The excel file Sheets("List1"), containing two columns with text/string.
Column A having starting word of paragraph or table and Column B having ending word of paragraph or table.

Based on column A and B text, the macro find the starting and ending word in source document.
If found then, copy all text or table including starting and ending word from source document with formatting and past it at bookmarks (Text1, Text2 and so on) in destination document with source formatting.

The paragraph I am trying to copy contains text and tables (either in between two text or at end)

How to loop column A and B text/string with loop of bookmark.

Below macro what I have try is find text based on column A and B in source document, copy with formatting and paste it at bookmark in destination document.

But it selecting range (text or table) of last entry in each loop. 
I have try to edit below code but not succeeded. I do not have good knowledge of coding.

Kindly look wonderful answer received from Macropod and my comments.

```
Sub CopyPasteParagraphsNew()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim DocSrc As Word.Document, DocTgt As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Dim WS As Worksheet, r As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim M As Long
Dim N As Long


Set WS = Sheets("List1")
  Set MsWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  On Error Resume Next
Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If wrdApp Is Nothing Then
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
bWeStartedWord = True
End If

With DocSrc

With MsWord
.Visible = True
.Documents.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Source Document.doc")
.Activate

MsWord.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
With MsWord.Selection.Find

M = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'selecting last string of column A and pasting at each bookmark
For i = 1 To M
.ClearFormatting
.Wrap = wdFindStop
.MatchCase = True
.Text = Cells(i, "A").Value
.Execute
MsWord.Selection.Collapse

Next i

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'selecting last string of column B and pasting at each bookmark
For j = 1 To N
lngStart = MsWord.Selection.End
.Text = Cells(j, "B").Value
.Execute

Next j
lngEnd = MsWord.Selection.End
MsWord.ActiveDocument.Range(lngStart, lngEnd).Copy

Set DocTgt = Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Destination Document.doc")
With DocTgt
 For t = 1 To DocTgt.Bookmarks.Count
If DocTgt.Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & t) Then

MsWord.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=("Text" & t)
MsWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting

End If
Next
End With
End With
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is unclear. Perhaps:

```
Sub CopyPasteParagraphs()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim DocSrc As Word.Document, DocTgt As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Dim WS As Worksheet, r As Long
Set WS = Sheets("List1")
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set DocSrc = .Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Source Document.doc") 'SourceDocument
  Set DocTgt = Documents.Open(ActiveDocument.Path & "\Destination Document.doc")
  With DocSrc
    For r = 1 To WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .Text = WS.Range("A" & r) & "*" & WS.Range("B" & r)
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
      End With
      If .Find.Found = True Then Set wdRng = .Duplicate
        With DocTgt
          If .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & r) Then
            .Bookmarks("Text" & r).Range.FormattedText = wdRng.FormattedText
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End With
    .Close False
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Instead of:

```
      If .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & r) Then
        .Bookmarks("Text" & r).Range.FormattedText = wdRng.FormattedText
      End If
```

you might use:

```
      If .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & r) Then
        wdRng.Copy
        .Bookmarks("Text" & r).Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
      End If
```

Comment: You would probably find it far easier if you simply bookmarked all the ranges in your source document. Then you'd only need two columns - one for the source bookmark and another for the destination bookmark.

Comment: So how do you know what words will be in the source document?

Comment: Images of excel sheet, source and destination document output of my and macropod added.

Comment: The problem is that your end text is inside the table. Put whatever you need to define the end of the range outside the table. Otherwise, you're effectively telling Word to not include the end of the last cell or the end of the table - which is impossible for it to do if you want the last cell copied.

Comment: Dear Sir, I have added "end" word after table for your code and working but source formatting getting change (if it contain table within two text). However, in my code copy paste only last row entry in each loop but maintaining formatting as well as able to include last table cell. Sir, thank you very much for healthy discussion and your valuable time and effort.

Comment: The change will be due to the inconsistent use of Styles in your documents. I've updated the answer to suggest a copy/paste approach that should work around that issue.

Comment: Dear Sir, working perfectly without any format change. Thank you very much for your time, healthy discussion and effort.